# Best practices for good DataGrid filtering performance?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, filter

I'm fairly new to C# and WPF, and I'm working on a fairly simple program that lists ~650 objects in a DataGrid, and uses the contents of a TextBox to filter out items that don't contain that string in a particular field.

However, the performance of the filtering and DataGrid are abysmal. It takes up to a couple of seconds for the application to become responsive again when typing in a search string, and even scrolling through the list of items in the table is slow and chunky.

I tried enabling virtualization on the table using the recycling mode, but it didn't seem to affect the performance at all.

Is databinding/filtering typically this slow with WPF? And are there best practices for deciding when to use databinding in WPF and when to update content in the code-behind?

Here's the majority of the code I'm using for this program:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
<DataGrid x:Name="ItemGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding VariableList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DisplayName}" IsReadOnly="True">                    
    </DataGridTextColumn> 
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And the code-behind:

```
private bool FilterVariables(object obj)
{
    DataGridItem = obj as DataGridItem;
    if (item == null) return false;

    string textFilter = SearchBox.Text;
    if (textFilter.Trim().Length == 0) return true; // the filter is empty - pass all items

    // apply the filter
    if (item.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(textFilter.ToLower())) return true;
    return false;
}

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the default view from the listview
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemGrid.ItemsSource);
    if (view != null)
    {
        view.Filter = null;
        view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterVariables);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
After revising some of my initial code (not posted) and removing references to a singleton in some of my code-behind, the performance improved dramatically. Unfortunately, I don't have a clear solution if anybody else runs into a similar issue, but I suspect my problem was either related to the use of the singleton or messy coding on my part.

Comment: Sounds to me like your DataGrid has lost its virtualization, and no WPF is not that slow. Post the full XAML and code required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you try to do the same thing with a GridView?

Comment: @HighCore - WPF is slow! and the DataGrid is a gigantic slow-mo, also it eats up huge amount of resources!
aswanson - you are doing pretty much everything correctly. I'm using very similar code to yours. One thing I did end up doing was not binding the CollectionViewSource to the DataGrid directly. Instead I filtered the CollectionViewSource on a background thread and then created a new ObservableCollection from the result and used that to bind the DataGrid. For me this worked faster, despite the DataGrid taking ~3s to refresh itself with lots of data...
PS! mark your question as answered!

Comment: @HighCore - I do know what I'm talking about (I have made many WPF apps myself). Yes you can have acceptable perforamnce out of WPF, but compared to more "native" code, eg. WinForms and GDI, WPF is way slower in more of the cases. Look at StackOverflow, it is riddeled with questions about slow this and that in WPF. DataGrid is another prime example - takes ages to refresh itself and consumes 80x more memory (when virtualization is turned off - http://tinyurl.com/m3nx2xm) compared to WinForms.

Comment: @HighCore - turning off virtualization is just to prove a point. And there are some corner cases where that might be necessary. You are correct that WinForms doesn't support complex UI-s very well. In my last big app I went with WPF precisely because of that, despite the fact that I can filter my 10k rows with 30+ columns of data in less than 500ms, but the rest of 3500ms I have to wait for the DataGrid to refresh itself which is annoying. I bet WinForms would be faster here, but the amount of extra UI coding doesn't justify that. PM me if you want to argue more, but lets keep this post clean.

Comment: @HighCore - yes I did read that. But not knowing what he changed or how his app works it is hard to argue for one case or the other. Maybe he ditched DataGrid altogher? Who knows. Comments are char limited so I couldn't fully explain myself at first go. My inital response was for those who stumble upon this thread, to let them know WPF/DataGrid can be that slow - in my app for instance, like I stated previously...